# I can't run localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, localhost

So I was running my localhost with a simple

```
 rails s
```

and it started fine:

```
 => Booting WEBrick
 => Rails 4.1.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
 => Run 'rails server -h' for more start up options
 => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
 => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

Then this message that appeared:

```
 A server is already running. Check C:/User/yahshef/sites/game/tmp/pids/server.pids.
 Exiting
```

I then checked 'C:/User/yahshef/sites/game/tmp/pids/server.pids' and inside it was:

```
9552
```

I deleted the 9552, but when I ran it, it started fine like the earlier one:

```
 => Booting WEBrick
 => Rails 4.1.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
 => Run 'rails server -h' for more start up options
 => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
 => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

Then this one had a big change, but it is still an error :(, it showed this:

```
Exiting
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in `kill': Invalid argument (Errno::EINVAL)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in `pidfile_process_status'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/server.rb:340:in `check_pid!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/server.rb:246:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ralities-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ralities-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'

        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ralities-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ralities-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ralities-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ralities-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

anyone know how to solve this? I appreciate it.

**EDIT**:

Please note that I did research BEFORE I posted this question

Comment: have you done any research to try and solve this problem? I did a google search on `rails `kill': Invalid argument (Errno::EINVAL)` and the first couple of results had reasonable looking answers.

Comment: @BryanOakley I did a google research before I posted the question, but none have the answer

Comment: _saying_ you did research and _showing_ you did research are two different things. Show us what you've tried to solve this problem. If you expect free help you've got to be willing to put in a little effort, too. And while it may seem like you're wasting  your time, it helps prevent _us_ from wasting our time in giving suggestions you've already tried that didn't work. How are we supposed to know what you've tried and what you've researched?

Comment: I found out the only way is to actually DELETE the file, and since it is not important I deleted it to get my server running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open terminal and run tasklist command. This will show you the list of processes and then run taskkill /pid PID(of the process) or simply paste the name.

```
tasklist
taskkill /pid PID /f
```

/f forcefully kill the process.
http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/kill-processes-from-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7/
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx

these two links can help you in detail.

Comment: I tried it, but when I run 'taskkill /pid PID /f' it gives an error that the process "PID" is not found

Comment: Man PID is an integer here which means process id. When you will run task list it will show you the list of processes with there PID. Check the number and replace it with PID in the next command.